# Reference request: Whitehead's lemma for semisimple Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple Lie algebra and let $V$ be a representation. One formulation of Whitehead's lemma is that the Lie algebra cohomology of $V$ is given by

$$H^{\bullet}(\mathfrak{g}, V) \cong (\bigwedge\nolimits^{\bullet}\mathfrak{g}^*)^{\mathfrak{g}} \otimes V^{\mathfrak{g}}.$$

Here superscript notation $U^{\mathfrak{g}}$ means that we take $\mathfrak{g}$-invariant elements of $U$. Since the $\mathfrak{g}$-invariant parts of $\mathfrak{g}^*$ and $\bigwedge^2 \mathfrak{g}^*$ are trivial, this implies in particular that $H^{1}(\mathfrak{g}, V) = H^{2}(\mathfrak{g}, V) = 0.$ It is this consequence which is what usually gets called the Whitehead lemmas. The proof given of these two cases is quite concrete and algorithmic, involving explicit computations with the Casimir (for example the proof given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead%27s_lemma_(Lie_algebra))).

On the other hand, the proof usually given of the full statement is much more abstract and non-constructive, using results in homological algebra (such as the proof in Weibel's book).

I am wondering if anyone knows of a reference where the full Whitehead lemma is proved in a more down-to-earth way, similar to the cases of degrees $1$ and $2$?